# "pip install malmo" in macOS does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, malmo

when I tried to install malmo using "pip install malmo" or "pip3 install malmo", but its trigger to

" Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement malmo (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for malmo"
error.

By the way, 'malmo' package is exist in pypi.
https://pypi.org/project/malmo/

how can i install malmo in my Mac??? and
what's the problem??

---

Detail:

OS: macOS Siera

python: 3.5.5, 3.6.5, 3.7.0 (using homebrew)

Comment: I just ran "pip install malmo" and it installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The file name under https://pypi.org/project/malmo/#files for macos is: `malmo-0.36.0.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl`

The cp37 suggest you need python 3.7

The 10_13 suggest you need MacOSX 10.13.3 (High Sierra) or higher. From your post it looks like your on 10.12

Also see: https://github.com/Microsoft/malmo/blob/master/doc/install_macosx.md which states:

> Installing dependencies for MacOSX
>
> ```
> Install Homebrew: http://www.howtogeek.com/211541/homebrew-for-os-x-easily-installs-desktop-apps-and-terminal-utilities/
>
> Install dependencies:
>     brew install python3
>     brew install ffmpeg boost-python3
>     brew cask install java8
>
> If you are installing from source (and not using "pip3 install malmo"), unzip the Malmo zip to some location (e.g. your home folder as assumed in the next step).
>
> Add export MALMO_XSD_PATH=~/MalmoPlatform/Schemas (or your Schemas location) to your ~/.bashrc and do source ~/.bashrc
>
> When you update Malmo you will need to update the MALMO_XSD_PATH too.
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> These instructions were tested on MacOSX 10.13.3 (High Sierra).

You may have better luck installing if you build from source.